# How to add table caption using df_print?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown, blogdown

In rmarkdown (I happen to be using blogdown), if we use a SQL code chunk, a table caption is added with `tab.cap` in the knitr code chunk. Is there a way to use `tab.cap` for a R code chunk that prints a tibble using `df_print = "kable"` in the YAML.

I know that using the kable function directly would work, but I'm looking to use `df_print`.

````
```{r}
datasets::mtcars %>%
  head(2) %>%
  knitr::kable(caption = "My caption")
```
````

[image: Example image]

**Reproducible Example**

````
---
title: Table Captions
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    df_print: "kable"
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "sql.sqlite")
```

```{sql, connection=db, tab.cap = "My Caption"}
WITH twoCol(a, b) AS (SELECT 1, 2 UNION SELECT 2, 4) SELECT a, b FROM twoCol;
```

```{r print-table, tab.cap = "Sample of the users table"}
datasets::mtcars %>%
  head(2)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is not mean to be an an answer, and I just want to show my own opinion.

`df_print` is used for printing data frames, and the output of your SQL code chunk is a **SQL TABLE**, not a **data frame**.

The chunk option `tab.cap` may just for SQL engine, which means we have to use function `kable()` directly to add table caption for **data frame**.

**PS:** As in the [Section 1.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html):

> At the moment, not all features of `rmarkdown::html_document` are supported in 
>       **blogdown**, such as `df_print`, `code_folding`, `code_download`, and so on.

However, I found that the `df_print` is supported in **blogdown**.

**EDIT:**

**sql table** is always printed with `kable()` no matter what `df_print` is. We can disable **sql table** caption by `tab.cap = NA`.

A table caption can be added by defining an chunk hook (e.g. `table_caption`). Insert the following code snippet at the top of the .rmd file (just a simple example):

````
```{r table_caption, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(table_caption = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(!before) 
    paste("<table><caption>", options$table_caption, 
      paste0("</caption><colgroup><col width='100'></col></colgroup>",
        "<thead><tr class='header'></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table><p>"),
      sep = '')
  else NULL
})
```
````

Then table captions can be added blow the tables.

````
```{sql, connection=db, tab.cap=NA, table_caption="sql table caption"}
WITH twoCol(a, b) AS (SELECT 1, 2 UNION SELECT 2, 4) SELECT a, b FROM twoCol;
```

```{r print-table, table_caption = "table caption"}
datasets::mtcars %>%
  head(2)
```
````

`

Comment: You are correct that `tab.cap` is just for the SQL engine. However, the SQL table return is really just a data.frame returned from `DBI::dbGetQuery`. I have found the [line from `knitr::engine.R`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/7386aa3960e8126f8accaa35341b578b7af44277/R/engine.R#L563) that adds the caption. My question becomes, is there a way to pass a parameter from the knitr code chunk options to `df_print`? Thanks @yihui-xie for adding the image.

Comment: I believe where this occurs in is `rmarkdown::knit_print.R` [line 22](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/e384063ffa8d7c30b33dc0fb70902128e87b16c8/R/knit_print.R#L22).